# NDB Query hangs for one set of criteria

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

UPDATED:
I do not have an entry in the index.yaml, expecting zig-zag to work fine on equalities (which it appears to in the datastore UI) and here is the actual query I'm making:

```
UploadBlock.query(
    UploadBlock.time_slices == timeslice,  # timeslice is each value in the repeated property
    UploadBlock.company == block.company,
    UploadBlock.aggregator_serial == block.aggregator_serial,
    UploadBlock.instrument_serial == block.instrument_serial)\
.fetch(10, keys_only=True)
```

I've cross-posted this because I didn't read the initial support page first, so this is also on the google forum at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/-7n8Y_tzCgM

I have a datastore query I make as an integral part of my system. It's an equality filter on four properties. When I make this query for one set of criteria, the query just hangs. It does not hang for this set of criteria in the datastore viewer, so I can see that there are only two results to return. I can fetch both of these entities by id without problem, but the query always hangs, both in remote shell and in production. The query is running fine for a multitude of different criteria, it appears to just be this one set. I have attempted replacing both entities so that the criteria still matches, but they have different ids and I get the same result.

For some more specific information, the four properties are defined as follows:

```
company = ndb.KeyProperty(indexed=True)
aggregator_serial = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
instrument_serial = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
time_slices = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True, repeated=True)
```

I'm running gcloud versions

```
Google Cloud SDK 207.0.0
app-engine-java 1.9.64
app-engine-python 1.9.71
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.69
beta 2018.06.22
bq 2.0.34
core 2018.06.22
gcloud
gsutil 4.32
```

Any help on what I should try for next steps would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the actual query code? Also you have an entry for this query in your index.yaml right?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the zig-zag - its performance *might* vary depending on the actual data. Try to add a composite index for the query to bypass it, see if that helps.

Comment: @DanCornilescu thanks for the response, I've used remote shell to run this query and let it run for about 16 hours without it finishing AND the datastore UI runs an equivalent query immediately, do those symptoms still fit with a zig-zag performance issue?

Comment: Unsure. But if adding an index helps the answer would probably be yes :)

Comment: In my case I noticed inconsistent results between my app's queries and the GQL queries in the console, with occasional/intermittent exceptions.

Comment: Hi Myles, did the suggestion from @DanCornilescu worked?

Comment: @FedericoPanunzio thanks for the follow-up, since this data is in production, I'm waiting for our release cycle before I make any changes to the system. As I've previously mentioned, I only see this on one entity, so reproducing in a sandboxed environment is has shown no difference.

Comment: The index did fix the issue. It's shocking to me that one entity could cause a whole query to hang indefinitely like this, but that's what it was.